# Yii fails to validate file size

Tags: upload, yii, validation, filesize

I created a file upload form in yii, but for some reasons, Yii fails to validate my file size (it DOES validate my file type though). 
This is my controller:

```
$file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'attachment');
if ((is_object($file) && get_class($file)==='CUploadedFile')) {
    $model->attachment = $file;
    if($model->validate(array('attachment')))
         $model->attachment->saveAs('upload/'.$file);
}
```

And this is my rules:

```
array('attachment', 'file', 'types'=>'zip, rar, 7z','allowEmpty' => true,'maxSize'=>1024*1024*5,'tooLarge'=>'File has to be smaller than 5MB'),
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: What does Yii report the file size as in the `$file` attributes. If I remember correct it's `$file->size`

Comment: I tried uploading a 2.25MB bmp file and it showed validation error for both file size and type (`$file->_size` was reported to be `2359350`). Then I tried uploading a 50MB rar file and it showed no validation error even though the upload did not happen.

Comment: I found the problem. All I have to do is configure the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in the INI file. Thanks for your help

Comment: @vader if you have figured out the solution, then post it as an answer, and accept it, helps keep the unanswered question count down for the yii tag. Its ok to accept your own answer.

Comment: @vader: Or, delete the question entirely. This issue has been raised hundreds of times before in questions that are easier to find anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I managed to solve the problem myself. All I need to do is configure upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in the INI file.